# AngularJs - Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am trying to create a Metro Tile type grid with Angular, to achieve this i want each of the tiles to be a different colour. So my plan of action was to create a function that would randomly pick a colour inside a loop (using `ng-repeat`). Here is what i have so far....

```html
<div class={{RandomColourClass()}} ng-repeat="stockRecord in GridStockRecords | filter:searchText">
  <div  >
    <h6>{{stockRecord.ProductGroupName}}</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

So as you can see i am setting the class name with a function called RandomColourClass, Here is the JS bits

```js
$scope.TileColours = [{colour:'thumbnail tile tile-blue'},{colour:'thumbnail tile tile-green'},{colour:'thumbnail tile tile-red'}];

$scope.RandomColourClass = function(){
  var randomColour = $scope.TileColours[Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.TileColours.length)];
  return randomColour.colour.toString();
};
```

This all works fine and the tiles are of different colours but i keep getting the following error

> Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!".

I've had a look at other posts around the issue but i can't figure out what i need to change to get it working!? Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: post `GridStockRecords` please

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Angular performs a **digest** function to update the DOM when your data changes.

During the digest, it recomputes all the values you have bound in the DOM, in this case `{{RandomColorClass()}}`.  If any of them change, it again performs a digest cycle (since some variables may depend on the value of of the changed variable, for example).

It does this repeatedly until two digests in a row result in the same values -- i.e, nothing has changed.

What's happening is that when a digest occurs, your `RandomColorClass()` function is being called and returns a different value.  This triggers an additional digest, where `RandomColorClass()` again returns a different value, which triggers another digest...

Can you see where this is going?  You shouldn't be generating random values in this manner -- instead, generate them in your scope and persist them.

One approach might be, in your scope:

```
function randomColourClass() { /* ... */ };

$scope.GridStockRecords.forEach(function(record) {
  record.colorClass = randomColourClass(); 
});
```

and HTML:

```
    <div ng-repeat="stockRecord in GridStockRecords | filter:searchText"
         ng-class="stockRecord.colorClass">
      <div>
        <h6>{{stockRecord.ProductGroupName}}</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Makes total sense! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem in IE10 turns ut that the problem was that I was redirecting using window.location.

```
window.location = "#route/yada";
```

Changed the code to

```
$location.path("/route/yada);
```

And that solved my issues. =D

Comment: Somthing strange with these methods of redirecting: $window.location.href can rise `$digest() iterations reached. Aborting error`, $location.path() sometimes doesn't work. I solved with $location.url("route/yada");

Answer (score 1):

Answer unrelated to this particular question, but I'm adding it here because it's on the Google front page when you search for the error message and it took me a bit until I figured it out:

I had something like this in my view:

```
<custom-tag data="[1,2,3]"/>
```

And the controller of the custom tag had a watcher set up on `$scope.data`. This caused AngularJS to barf because every time it re-checked the value of `data` it got a new object from the view (remember, the array is an object) so it never finished digesting it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I mistyped ng-class="submit()" instead of ng-click="submit()". I can't imagine anyone else making such a silly error, but for the record, this is another way to create 10 $digest() iterations reached aborting!