# How to reproduce the "10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting" error in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

There have been a few questions asked about how to address the error message:

> 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting,

for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693410/angularjs-error-10-digest-iterations-reached-aborting). I get how to fix that - you change your code so it doesn't change the `$scope` during a `digest`.

What I'd like to do, and don't understand how to do, is reproduce this error as part of a Karma/Jasmine test. From what I've gathered, you need to [manually force a digest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316940/how-to-resolve-q-all-promises-in-jasmine-unit-tests) to generally get digest updates, and that works for me in terms of forcing the initial digest (to resolve promises), but I don't see it force the `$digest` loop that eventually errors out.

Comment: There aren't enough questions about how to cause an error, far too many about how to make it go away without understanding it.  _To reach enlightenment, you must first understand how to fail._

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when a function returns different value each time it is called.

Example

```js
$scope.getValue = function() {
  return Math.Random()
}
```

```html
<div>{{ getValue() }}</div>
```

Running the above code will generate the error as it returns a different value each time.

Another example

```js
$scope.getObjects = function() {
  return [object1, object2];
}
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="object in getObjects"></div>
```

In the second example, we generate a new array every time which causes the error.

Reference : https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time, but this doesn't answer the question. As I said, I know how to fix it, the question is how to reproduce in karma/jasmine.